# Не понимаю, почему изображение заменяется белым при вставке

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def create_top():
top = Toplevel(root,bg='black')
top.geometry('300x400+400+300')
top.title('Ответ')
im_top = PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\Домашний\\Desktop\\Данил\\прога проект\\Новая папка (2)\\Otvet.png")
top_fon = Label(top, height=200, width=300, image=im_top)
top_fon.place(x=0, y=200)
```

[image: Вот скрин]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что из коробки `Tkinter PhotoImage` поддерживает только: `GIF and PGM/PPM` [Documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)!

Для отображения `png` и других форматов можно взять `Pillow`

1. `pip install Pillow` - установка.
2. Usage:

   ```
   def create_top( self ):
      top = tk.Toplevel ( root , bg='black' )
      top.geometry ( '300x400+400+300' )
      top.title ( 'Ответ' )
      im = PIL.Image.open ( "C:\\Users\\Домашний\\Desktop\\Данил\\прога проект\\Новая папка (2)\\Otvet.png" )
      photo = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage ( im )

      label = Label ( root , image=photo )
      label.image = photo  # keep a reference!
      label.pack ( )
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что при выходе из функции изображение удаляется сборщиком мусора. Попробуйте как-то так:

```
top_fon = Label(top, height=200, width=300, image=im_top)
top_fon.im_top = im_top
```

Comment: Кстати да, это важное уточнение на счёт ссылки. Но это будет работать только с python 2.7 и выше вроде как.

Comment: Не могу точно ответить на это, поскольку Tk в основном использовал с Tcl. Помню, что при попытке создать image photo из файла или данных не поддерживаемого формата (JPEG) Tcl вылетает с ошибкой. От Python логично ожидать того же самого.